# Microarray Limma package, in topTable function don't assign ID for probsets column

Tags: r, bioconductor

I tried a tutorial by [Daniel Swan](http://bioinformatics.knowledgeblog.org/2011/06/20/analysing-microarray-data-in-bioconductor)  ,it works perfectly well. But I'm facing a problem in **topTable** function of **limma package**.

The "topTable" function create a **"probeset list"** but this probset list have not **"ID"** header (other columns name is their sample name, but Probe list column have not name (ID)).

At the result,  when I am runing:

```
gene.symbols <- getSYMBOL(probeset.list$ID, "hgu133plus2")
```

I'm getting the following error

```
  Error in .select(x, keys, columns, keytype = extraArgs[["kt"]], jointype = jointype): 
      'keys' must be a character vector
```

topTable is:

```
               logFC  AveExpr        t      P.Value    adj.P.Val        B
204779_s_at 7.367790 4.171707 72.77347 3.284937e-15 8.969850e-11 20.25762
207016_s_at 6.936667 4.027733 57.39252 3.694641e-14 5.044293e-10 19.44987
209631_s_at 5.192949 4.003992 51.24892 1.170273e-13 1.065182e-09 18.96660
```

my expression Set achieved by simpleaffy (gcrma) package. 
I'm runing R 3.0.2 under windows 7 with latest bioconductor packages, simpleaffy_2.38.0 , limma_3.18.13 and anotation files: hgu133plus2.db_2.10.1 ,hgu133plus2probe_2.13.0, hgu133plus2cdf_2.13.0

I would be very thankful, if somebody could help me.

Comment: Have you tried using `rownames(probeset.list)` instead of `probeset.list$ID`?

Comment: Thanks, very much David, its work for this situation. But blank probsets column name is unsolved. I searched for hours, even with google I couldn’t find any solution on this problem.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be an ID column (I don't believe the docs mention one)? If you want there to be an ID column, just do `probeset.list$ID = rownames(probeset.list)`.

Comment: Your suggestion work well and probably is my solution. But, in all examples that I've seen, an "ID" is returned by function. many of the people work by `....$ID` but no one encountered a similar problem. I think, there is a problem with _expressionSet_ object or `topTable` function that confused me.

Comment: It looks like the behavior of `toptable` has changed (with the version of limma) in the three years since the [tutorial you link to](http://bioinformatics.knowledgeblog.org/2011/06/20/analysing-microarray-data-in-bioconductor/). There's nothing wrong with the ExpressionSet object: you could create a minimal example for limma, for instance with the lines `m = replicate(4, rnorm(100)); d = data.frame(condition=c(1, 1, 0, 0)); rownames(m) = paste("gene", 1:100); e = eBayes(lmFit(m, d)); print(toptable(e))`. The IDs are stored in the rownames

Comment: Ah, actually I found the reason: see edit to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDs are not stored as an `ID` column, but as the rownames of the table. Change the line to:

```
gene.symbols <- getSYMBOL(rownames(probeset.list), "hgu133plus2")
```

If you want there to be an ID column instead of using row names, you can assign one with:

```
probeset.list$ID = rownames(probeset.list)
```

---

According to the documentation of the `toptable` function, the ID column will exist if and only if there are duplicated gene names:

> ```
>  If ‘fit’ had unique rownames, then the row.names of the above
>  data.frame are the same in sorted order. Otherwise, the row.names
>  of the data.frame indicate the row number in ‘fit’. If ‘fit’ had
>  duplicated row names, then these are preserved in the ‘ID’ column
>  of the data.frame, or in ‘ID0’ if ‘genelist’ already contained an
>  ‘ID’ column.
> ```

In the other examples you've seen ID used, there must have been duplicate gene names in the input. This makes sense because R typically doesn't like having duplicated rownames (but has no problem having duplicate IDs in a column).

Answer (score 1):

Hope my piece of working codes can make your question clear:

```
library(limma) # загружаем нужную библиотека
library(siggenes)
library(cluster)
library(stats)

data <- read.table("AneurismDataAllProbesGenesisLog2NormalizedExperAndGenes.tab", sep = "\t", header = TRUE) # read from file

q = as.matrix(data) # данные в матрицу

b = as.matrix(cbind(data[, 2:10], data[, 11:14])) # cмежные колонки данных
m = normalizeQuantiles(b, ties=TRUE)
f = data.frame(condition = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)) # дизайн
fit = lmFit(m, f) # линейная модель
e = eBayes(fit) # тест Байеса
volcanoplot(e, coef=1, highlight=5, names=data$GeneName, xlab="Log Fold Change", ylab="Log Odds", pch=19, cex=0.67, col = "dark blue") # график-вулкан
z = rownames(m) = data[, 1]
hc <- hclust(dist(m), "ave") # кластерграмма
plot(hc)
plot(hc, hang = -1)  

print(e$coefficients) # output eBayes coefficients
print(e$p.value) # get out the P values
toptable(e) # select 10 most differentialy expressed genes, the disadvantage that it outputs only the gene row number and not the name
printresult <-toptable(e) # assign the result to a variable
write.csv(printresult, file = "eBayesTableAneurism", row.names = TRUE) # write to the file in the current folder
 volcanoplot(e, coef=1, highlight=10, names=data[,1], xlab="Log Fold Change", ylab="Log Odds", pch=19, cex=0.67, col = "red") # график-вулкан c именами
volcanoplot(e, coef=1, highlight=5, names=data[,1], xlab="Log Fold Change", ylab="Log Odds", pch=19, cex=0.67, col = "blue") # график-вулкан с именами (Volcano with gene names)
```